# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, mstest

Please note that I am following along on this course, and am presently in module 5: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/wcf-end-to-end

The problem is that I am trying to run the unit tests, but every time I do I get the above error.  Here is the full stack trace:

https://pastebin.com/aQHeeUyp

I can get it to work with `NUnit`, but if I switch the project to `MsTest` then I get the above error.   Please note that I have researched various posts like the following but have not resolved the error:

[VS2017 Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525487/vs2017-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-visualstudio-qualitytools-unitt)

[Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel, Version=11.0.0.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155559/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-visualstudio-testplatform-objectmodel)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/4c69c666-85ca-4d1c-b3ad-ff564578743d/unit-tests-are-not-running-not-seeing-existing-unit-tests-added-new-unit-test-project-empty?forum=vsunittest

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d44322f6-9850-4c3f-8696-921d3bc9db85/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftvisualstudioqualitytoolsunittestframework?forum=vsunittest

Here is the full source code:

```
https://github.com/john1726/WcfEndToEnd.git
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Microsoft changed some assemblies/namespaces among other things for their unit testing framework and somehow broke something or there may be a problem with `ReSharper` so I ended up sticking with `NUnit`.